# C# & WPF: connection with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database

I am working with a project in C# using WPF, connected to a SQL Server database. I can insert data into a table, delete, update and select.

For example I have a table with a column `Parts` and another `Quantity`.

I have these sample values: Parts: `Tires` and Quantity: `3`.

What I want to do is when I once choose the tires, the quantity would become 2; i.e, **Quantity(2)**. Thanks to everyone!

The code-behind is:

```
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database = autoser; Integrated Security = true");

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Part FROM autoparts WHERE Part LIKE '%" + txtpart.Text + "%'", conn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("dtkerkimi");                          
    da.Fill(dt);

    datag.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapt.Fill(ds);
    conn.Close();

    int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There isn't a part that you are looking for!");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Congrats");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to issue a SQL update statement? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx 

Your example is also an excellent example of how to create a SQL Injection vulnerability (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).  I would strongly recommend researching parameterized SQL.

Comment: No, what i want to do when i choose tires in the part field, the quantity  should be deducted from three to two. And after some time when i choose again tires  the quantity should be deducted from two to one.....

Comment: Can you provide code for how people choose a part or select a quantity?  Is there an event handler attached to some event on a control?

Comment: DVK, i'm a bit confused about that part, for moment i don't have code to do that, i have in sql part and quantity field. The quantity field should be decreased automatically, after i choose the part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select statement will only get data, it cannot update it. For that you will need an update statement similar to the one below

```
SqlCommand upDateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE autoparts SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE Part Like  '%" + txtpart.Text + "%'", conn);
```

This should find the part you want and then reduce the quantity by 1 (if it's 0 it will reduce it to -1, if you don't want that to happen then put the code that uses the update command in the else block of your code sample).

However this risks a [sql injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) attack. A safer approach would be to use parameters which give protection against these forms of attack.

```
        var upDateCommand = new SqlCommand
        {
            CommandText = "UPDATE autoparts SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE Part = @partName"
        };
        upDateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partName", txtpart.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the SQL you are looking for to Update and Return Result

```
UPDATE autoparts
SET    autoparts.Quantity = autoparts.Quantity-1 
OUTPUT DELETED.Part
WHERE   autoparts.Part like '%Tires%'
```